# Python (Sum of expense, income, and profit)

Tags: python, loops, sum

In Python I have a list of entries. I need to get the sum of expenses, the sum of income, and the profit. I've been able to get the expenses and income. Looking to break out the profit. I know I'm missing something simple but can't figure it out.

```
entries = entries = [
    {'date': '2021-01-01', 'transaction': 'Expense', 'amount': '50', 'note': 'Lemons'},
    {'date': '2021-01-02', 'transaction': 'Income', 'amount': '100', 'note': 'Sales'}
]

#Print Income
for entry in entries:
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'income':
        income = 0
        income += int(entry['amount'])
        print(f"The total income is ${income}")

# Print Expense
for entry in entries:
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'expense':
        expense = 0
        expense += int(entry['amount'])
        print(f"The total expenses are ${expense}")

# Print Profit
for entry in entries:
    profit = 0
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'expense':
        profit -= int(entry['amount'])
    elif entry['transaction'].lower() == 'income':
        profit += int(entry['amount'])

print(profit)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. What does "break out the profit" mean? What result do you get when you try this code, and *how is that different* from the expected result? Also, what happened when you tried to trace through the intended logic of the code? (Hint: **how many times** should lines of code like `income = 0`, `expense = 0` and `profit = 0` happen? Why? Therefore, should they be inside the loops, or outside?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you just want to calculate the profit/expenses/income for the entire
list, so you shouldn't set "profit = 0" after every iteration, instead just set it in the beginning.

```
entries = entries = [
    {'date': '2021-01-01', 'transaction': 'Expense', 'amount': '50', 'note': 'Lemons'},
    {'date': '2021-01-02', 'transaction': 'Income', 'amount': '100', 'note': 'Sales'}
]

#Print Income
income = 0
for entry in entries:
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'income':
        income += int(entry['amount'])
        print(f"The total income is ${income}")

# Print Expense
expense = 0
for entry in entries:
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'expense':
        expense += int(entry['amount'])
        print(f"The total expenses are ${expense}")

# Print Profit
profit = 0
for entry in entries:
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'expense':
        profit -= int(entry['amount'])
    elif entry['transaction'].lower() == 'income':
        profit += int(entry['amount'])

print(profit)
```

Answer (score -1):

your profit in for loop will be reset equal to 0 when you decide transaction is expense or income

```
entries = entries = [
    {'date': '2021-01-01', 'transaction': 'Expense', 'amount': '50', 'note': 'Lemons'},
    {'date': '2021-01-02', 'transaction': 'Income', 'amount': '100', 'note': 'Sales'}
]

#Print Income
for entry in entries:
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'income':
        income = 0
        income += int(entry['amount'])
        print(f"The total income is ${income}")

# Print Expense
for entry in entries:
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'expense':
        expense = 0
        expense += int(entry['amount'])
        print(f"The total expenses are ${expense}")

# Print Profit
profit = 0
for entry in entries:
    if entry['transaction'].lower() == 'expense':
        profit -= int(entry['amount'])
    elif entry['transaction'].lower() == 'income':
        profit += int(entry['amount'])
        
print(profit)
```

I think it will be solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help, pulling the variable out the loop will help for all instances and I won't always just have those 2 rows.